# InDesign line composing for left alignment

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, typography, paragraph, hyphenation

I see this kind of text alignment (alternation of long line/short line over and over) in many books lately.

[image]
[image]

I wonder if there is any way to achieve this with a combination of specific justification + hyphenation settings in InDesign? Does a specific line or paragraph composer exist for this? Or is every line break just manually done? (which seems like a crazy thing to do for hundreds-pages books...)
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Nothing tricky really. Just add left indent in your paragraph styles. Justification is not relevant here, since the paragraph are... not justified ^^

Comment: Hi @Vinny, thanks for your interest but what I meant really isn't about the indents on the left of a text block — I was actually wondering if there is a setting to automatically hyphenate/align things like that on the right side of the text block, so one line is long, next one is shorter, and so on. Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Now I understand your question. It's a bit confusing that you are showing an example with those left indents. Anyway I don't think there is a simple answer to your question. None of the Hyphenation and Justification settings does this automatically.

Comment: Hey @Vinny, yes you are right, I may not have used the proper example! Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this just in case anyone was wondering.

There is actually a plugin for that: https://github.com/freder/extendscripts/tree/master/indesign/flattersatz

The plugin is quite old though, not sure it works with any InDesign version.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/141017/84899) except there the OP wanted justified text. Perhaps it works with ragged lines as well?

Comment: @Wolff Yes! In fact the plugin does exactly that—it creates transparent rectangles every second line, and yes it works both with ragged and justified lines. Honestly I must say that when it comes to multiple layouts, doing it manually as you suggested in the other thread is just easier and gives you complete control over the text. The plugin works well if you just have one simple layout throughout the whole book.