# Adobe InDesign: Set text justify for every other line

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I'm looking for a solution to achieve something like the image below.

I want to set justify and hyphenation for paragraphs except odd lines.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can I ask why? Or rather, what is the reasoning behind this eccentric lay-out choice? To me, it looks both extremely ugly (subjectively) and hindering legibility because of the irregular shape.

Comment: I think it is about style. However I don't think it looks good but would like to learn some techniques.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this just by styling. You could use *Right Indent* for every second line, but that would require you to make manual line breaks which would be a mess.

I will suggest something different. Why not use *Text Wrap* for this? Simply make the paragraph justified and use invisible rectangles which prohibits every second line from having the full length.

Place a rectangle with the wanted width on every odd line and apply *Text Wrap* set to *Wrap around bounding box* with no *Offset*.

[image]

Make the rectangles transparent and place them on the *Master Page* (or simply copy/paste them onto each page where you need the styling).

[image]

Comment: oh thats a possible way to do it, thanks

Comment: @wonglo, you're welcome! Remember to *accept* the answer if you find that it answers your question and a better answer doesn't come along.